# How to have labels with spacings in Javascript c3 charts?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

Below is the c3 charts code snippet. I require that the bar label in the x-axis be "Total gain". But I am not able to get that, only single word(s) without a space is allowed like "Totalgain". Please refer comment below.

```
c3.generate({
    data: {
           columns: Figurefour,
           groups: [
                    ['Trending', 'Total gain']
                ],
           colors: {
                    Trending: '#33fefe',
                    Total gain : '#22cfcf'//"Total gain" errors out, only single word(s) like "Totalgain" allowed(no spaces).
                }
     }
});
```

Is there a way to get the lables with spaces work?

Answer (score 2):

Just put quotes around it, like so

```
    ...
    "Total gain" : '#22cfcf'
}
...
```